# DatagridviewDoubleClick event duplicated

Tags: c#

I have a block of code like this:

```
void d_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.RowIndex >= 0) && (e.RowIndex < d.Rows.Count))
        cur = d.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();
    empID = d.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    if (isAlist == false)
    {
        te.Text = empID;
    }
    else
    {
        //empID += d.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        //empID+=",";

        te.Text += empID;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(d.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    f.Hide();
}
```

`d` is a `DataGridview`.
The problem is when I double click on a row for the second time, the value is duplicated, For example: First time I double-click on a row with value"bob", the console will print "bob", but for the second time I double-click on a row, the console print like this:

> "bob"
>   "jake"
>   "jake"

the 3rd time is

> "bob"
>    "jake"
>    "jake"
>    "mike"
>    "mike"
>    "mike"

I don't know how to fix this

Comment: How you want your result then? Just print 'bob' when you click on 'bob' row. and next time you click 'jack' just print 'jack' ?????

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in the handler to see if it gets called multiple times?

Comment: yes that what i want, and what is the breakpoint?

Comment: If you don't know what a breakpoint is, go and find out. Google is your friend, SO is not the right place to ask about it. However your symptoms look like you are right in the title. So right click on the method header `d_CellMouseDoubleClick` and choose _find all ocurrances_! Look if there is a line like this `this.d.CellMouseDoubleClick+= new System.EventHandler( this.d_CellMouseDoubleClick);`. There should be __one__ and it should be in the _designer.cs_ file. If there is another one or if it is elsewhere that is probably the problem..